# Add bias with tf.conv2d - Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

Note, that it is not `tf.layers.conv2d`, see [reference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/2.0.1/#conv2d).

I can't find a parameter which could be passed as a bias of convolution. See example:

```js
//(3x3x3)
const images = tf.tensor([
  //image
  [
    //height
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]], //width
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
  ],
  //image
  [
    //height
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]], //width
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
  ]
]);

//(2x2x2)
const filters = tf.tensor(
  [ //height
    [ //width
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
    ],
    [ //width
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
    ]
  ]
)

const stride = 1;

images.conv2d(filters, stride, 0).print()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```

Works well, however, NHWC format really confuses me especially with filters, and there's no way to set them to NCHW with filters, just input, but the main issue is that I can't find a way to add bias per out depth. Is there any way, or workaround for that?

Comment: Could you not set the dataformat of the input this way :`images.conv2d(filters, stride, 0, 'NCHW')` ?

Comment: I can, but it is just for the input format, the filters must be NHWC

Comment: What constraint do you have for the filters to have such a format ? Because you can always transpose your tensor from NCHW to NHWC and unlike the image tensor which might be generated by library on which we might have little or less control, we generally have control over the filters

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it just involves an unnecessary operation, and I'm building it from scratch to actually understand it step-by-step. Also, it doesn't solve the bias problem.

Comment: See my answer on how you can add the bias with `tf.add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/2.0.1/#conv2d), the dataformat can be passed as an argument to `tf.conv2d`. Additionnally to add bias `tf.add` can be used as demonstrated below:

```js
//(3x3x3)
const images = tf.tensor([
  //image
  [
    //height
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]], //width
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
  ],
  //image
  [
    //height
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]], //width
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
    [[255,255,255],[55,55,55],[0,0,0]],
  ]
]);

//(2x2x2)
const filters = tf.tensor(
  [ //height
    [ //width
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
    ],
    [ //width
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
      [ //pixel, prevdepth
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
        [ //nextdepth
          0, 3
        ],
      ],
    ]
  ]
)

const stride = 1;

conv = images.conv2d(filters, stride, 0, 'NCHW')
add = conv.add([2, 3])
add.print()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```